# Usage of comma before "and"

Tags: conjunctions

This is a sentence from the article "Travel in Southeast Asia". It is about Laos.

> In addition to pagodas and historical sites, Wat Sisaket Temple with its big Buddha image, old Hotai library whose walls are covered with sapphires, and wall paintings are well worth seeing.

In this sentence, I am so confused with the following question:

> The wall of Hotai library are covered with ____

Possible answers:

- sapphires
- sapphires and wall painting

I wanted to know the **usage of comma** before "and" in this sentence.

Comment: Please look closely at your question. Can see see what is wrong with your use of commas _throughout the entire first sentence,_ and also in the rest of the question?

Comment: I means ''comma''after  the word '' sapphires''.

Comment: I am still hoping that you will look at the commas in the sentence that begins with _In addition to pagodas..._ and that you will see what is wrong with the commas in that sentence!

Comment: What is the source? By whom or where written might give insight into the writing style, which is unclear at best. If the Hotai library walls are covered with sapphires and wall paintings, then no comma. Or maybe the wall paintings are a separate item in the list of historical sites, and not related to the sapphires. In that case, leave the comma in. But there are other problems with the sentence that also need to be cleared.

Comment: @user3169 It's from a Burmese Facebook site for English learners, e.g. [**here.**](https://www.facebook.com/sein.tun.100/posts/1670110766560142) But I hesitate to add it as a source, because it's not exactly as cited. For instance, the commas have _spaces_ after them!

Comment: Yes, I have edied it.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The enumeration seems to indicate that the "wall paintings" are a separate item. The quote should be written this way, including the "-" after *paintings*.

Comment: Well done @learner !! Punctuation is very important in English!

Comment: Does anyone else think the verb should be **is**? I'm parsing this as *subject* = "Wat Sisaket Temple"; *preposition* = "with"; *objects of preposition* = 1. its big Buddha image, 2. (its) old Hotai library whose walls are covered with sapphires, and 3. (its) wall paintings.

Comment: Huh. Googling fragments of the OP's question, I find that there are still differences between the quoted passage and what Google finds. These differences would make my verb suggestion incorrect. I agree with spongessuck. This passage is badly written.

Answer (score 1):

The passage in question is badly written, so it's not surprising that you're confused.

I think "sapphires" is the answer, since the commas here are separating items in a list. So the sapphires are on the walls in the library, and the wall paintings are elsewhere in the temple.